# How to retain previous value for a textbox in onchange event in usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have an user control with a few textboxes in it and how can I retain previous value of a textbox txtOne if a condition is not met in OnTextChanged event for the sum of txtA, txtB, txtC textboxes.

The variable "one" is considered as a previous value of the textbox. I have added the below code in usercontrol.

```
protected void txtOne_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    total = Convert.ToInt32(txtA.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtB.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtC.Text);
    if (total > Convert.ToInt32(txtOne.Text.ToString()))
    {
         txtOne.Text = one.ToString();
    }
}
```

Here "one" variable is getting value as 0. It should store previous value. Could you please give me a clue on where to store the value in "one" variable.

Comment: *Never* use Convert.ToInt32(), always Int32.TryParse().  You cannot expect the user to always press the right key.  Updating txtOne in an event handler for the txtOne.TextChanged event does not otherwise make much sense and is likely to trigger the crash that this web site is named for.

Comment: Could you please provide me with an example.

Comment: Very hard to write a useful example from a snippet that doesn't make any sense.  Blindly guessing: get ahead by making txtOne a Label instead of a TextBox.  And use the TextChanged event handlers of those other 3 boxes, they should call a method that computes the sum and updates the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below is not in any way optimized or generalized. It is as close to your sample code as possible & designed to show you an answer based on your original code. I would suggest using comboboxes rather than textboxes, and/or using validation to make sure that the entries are all numeric. The code below doesn't go that far - it only answers your question based on the code you provided:

```
TextBox txtA = new TextBox();
    TextBox txtB = new TextBox();
    TextBox txtC = new TextBox();
    int total = 0;
    TextBox txtOne = new TextBox();
    string newOne = "";
    string someDefaultValue = "";
    string lastOne = "";
    if(txtA.Text.Length==0||txtB.Text.Length==0||txtC.Text.Length==0){
        //user has not entered required fields -- abort
        return;
    }
    bool isTextChanging = true;//CHANGE TO FALSE AT END OF PAGE_ONLOAD
    protected void txtOne_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!isTextChanging){
        isTextChanging=true;
        total = getTotal(new string[] { txtA.Text, txtB.Text, txtC.Text });
        if (total > -1)
        {
            int totalTest = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(txtOne.Text, out totalTest))
            {
                if (total > totalTest)
                {
                    txtOne.Text = lastOne.Length > 0 ? lastOne : someDefaultValue;//default value for the first run when there is no last value 
                    lastOne = newOne;//whatever the value of "one" is this time
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("YOu must only enter numbers");
            }
        }
        }
        isTextChanging=false;
    }
    private int getTotal(string[] inputs)
    {
        int total = 0;
        int subTotal = 0;
        foreach(string input in inputs)
        {
            if(int.TryParse(input,out subTotal)){
                total += subTotal;
            }else{
                MessageBox.Show("You must only enter numbers");
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return total;
    }
```

Comment: It does not work as expected because I am using UserControl and adding TextChanged in UserControl. First I am trying to initialize the value of lastOne variable  with txtOne.Text in Page_Load event and it is firing 5 times because I am having 5 usercontrols. Could you please suggest me, where I have to initialize with last value?

Comment: You missed the part about this not being an optimized or generalized answer but just an example of how to do what you're asking. I'm not entirely sure what your problem is, but I'd bet it's because the example I give  you links onchanged events to several controls. To avoid all of them firing at once, add a Boolean like my revised code example above. Just set isTextChanging=true any time you want to change the textboxes without triggering their onChanged events.

Comment: In reality, you would also want to kill the processing if two of the textboxes remained blank -- only process if all textboxes are full. I told you that textboxes are not a good way of doing this - and I answered the specific question you asked. You still need to use your brain to finalize the solution, or ask another question about it.

Comment: I have no way of knowing what else you may or may not know. If you are still having problems, message me here and I'll see if I can't help you - otherwise I can only answer the question(s) you ask.

Comment: I am asking just a simple question. I have a txtOne.text control with value as 10 initially and if the user enters 110 which exceeds 100(forget about where we get 100), then we need to revert its value to 10. The lastOne variable returns 0 instead of 10 here in the TextChanged event. I want to preserve the value of 10 in lastOne variable.

Comment: Is this web or win form?

Comment: This is a web form

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I'm confused. It may be a language thing. Is this what you're trying to accomplish, but with textboxes instead of dropdownlists?

Front end:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="SO_Web.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="div_Boxes" runat="server">

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Back End:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        createBoxes();
    }
    string[] boxNames = { "One", "Two", "Three" };
    private void createBoxes()
    {

        int x = 0;
        int y = 10;
        Panel p = new Panel();
        foreach (string name in boxNames)
        {

            Label l = new Label();
            l.ID = "lbl_" + name;
            l.Text = "Select Value " + name;
            l.Style.Add("float", "left");
            DropDownList c = new DropDownList();
            c.ID = "cbx_" + name;
            c.Items.Add("Select One");
            for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
            {
                c.Items.Add(i.ToString());
            }
            c.SelectedIndex = 0;
            c.AutoPostBack = true;
            c.Style.Add("display", "block");
            c.SelectedIndexChanged += cbx_Changed;
            p.Controls.Add(l);
            p.Controls.Add(c);
        }

        Label lbl_Total = new Label();
        lbl_Total.Text = "Your Total:";
        TextBox txt_Total = new TextBox();
        txt_Total.ID = "txt_Total";
        txt_Total.Width = 75;
        p.Controls.Add(lbl_Total);
        p.Controls.Add(txt_Total);
        p.Width = 300;
        p.Height = 200;
        div_Boxes.Controls.Add(p);
    }
    protected void cbx_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool proceed = true;
        int total = 0;
        foreach (string name in boxNames)
        {
            DropDownList c = (DropDownList)findControl(this.Page.Controls,"cbx_" + name);
            if (c.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                proceed = false;
            }
            else
            {
                total += c.SelectedIndex;

            }
        }
        if (proceed)
        {
            ((TextBox)findControl(this.Page.Controls,"txt_Total")).Text = total.ToString("C2");
        }

    }
    private Control findControl(ControlCollection page, string id)
    {
        foreach (Control c in page)
        {
            if (c.ID == id)
            {
                return c;
            }

            if (c.HasControls())
            {
                var res = findControl(c.Controls, id);

                if (res != null)
                {
                    return res;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But you want to use texboxes and allow the user to type entries, and you want a MAX value of 110. If the user enters values under 110 for all three boxes, you want the total. If the user enters >110 for any box, you want the value reset to 100? Is that correct?